# obtaining a variable/method from model to contoller, so i can post the variable to a view

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, variables, model, controller

I'm trying to create a *variable* `latitude` in my pages controller that has a value of the `long_lat_parser.lon`. I want that *variable* to send over to the **home.html view**!!

**PagesController** that hooks to home page.html to view my variable:

```rails
class PagesController < ApplicationController

def place_params
  long_lat_parser = LongLatParser(image)
  {place_attributes: {longitude:  long_lat_parser.lon,  latitude: long_lat_parser.lat}}
end

def home
    @post = Post.new
    @posts = Post.all
    @places = Place.all
    @place = Place.new

    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params.merge(place_params))
    #@latitude = Post.save_image_exif(params[:latitude])
end
```

**lotlangparser model:**

```rails
class LotLangParser

  after_create :initialize

  def initialize(image)
    @image = image
    @exif_data = MiniExiftool.new(image.queued_for_write[:original].path)
  end

  def lat
    parse_latlong(exif_data['gpslatitude'])
  end

  def lon
    parse_latlong(exif_data['gpslongitude'])
  end

  private

  def parse_latlong(latlong)
    return unless latlong
    match, degrees, minutes, seconds, rotation = /(\d+) deg (\d+)' (.*)" (\w)/.match(latlong).to_a
    calculate_latlong(degrees, minutes, seconds, rotation)
  end

  def calculate_latlong(degrees, minutes, seconds, rotation)
    calculated_latlong = degrees.to_f + minutes.to_f/60 + seconds.to_f/3600
    ['S', 'W'].include?(rotation) ? -calculated_latlong : calculated_latlong
  end
end
```

All in all i want to take this lat indiviualy and long and put them into the html view!! how would i post it to the view?  `<%= long_lat_parser.lon %>` ??

Comment: Not understand your problem, please add complete code. also fix the method call,  you are calling `save_image_exif` from controller like `Post.save_image_exif(params[:latitude])`. Its totally wrong, because parameters not match, also you are calling `class method` but you declare method as `instance_method`.    So first fix this issues

Comment: I would also like to draw your attention again to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37087454/nomethoderror-in-postscontrollercreate-undefined-method-latitude-saving-lat/37087808#37087808
You can eliminate all you problems if you simply pull out the exif parsing logic into a proper class with single responsibility.
Cheers

Comment: i updated my question but im still uncertain how I can make a variable for lat and long. Iv been trying to use the **function** place_params and the `long_lat_parser.lat` to get it. iv tried `@lati = long_lat_parser.lat`